# get the client from pyspark

Tags: hdfs, pyspark

I want to retrieve a list of file. I saw a post sayong that these commands would do the job:

```
from hdfs import Config
client = Config().get_client('dev')
client.list('/*')
```

But actually, execution fails:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HdfsError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-308-ab40dc16879a> in <module>()
----> 1 client = Config().get_client('dev')

/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/hdfs/config.py in get_client(self, alias)
    117           break
    118       else:
--> 119         raise HdfsError('Alias %r not found in %r.', alias, self.path)
    120     return self._clients[alias]
    121 

HdfsError: Alias 'dev' not found in '/home/sbenet/.hdfscli.cfg'.
```

As you can see, it is trying to access the file `/home/sbenet/.hdfscli.cfg` which does not exists.

If I want to use this method to retrieve the list of files, I need to fix this .hdfscli.cfg file issue, or to use another method with `sc` maybe.

Comment: You can access the Java context which exposes a `hadoopConfiguration` property via `sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()`

Comment: @Tzach Zohar, I tried it. I receive `JavaObject id=o1360 `. What do I do with this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a configuration file first. Check this out [1](https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#configuration)

```
[global]
default.alias = dev

[dev.alias]
url = http://dev.namenode:port
user = ann

[prod.alias]
url = http://prod.namenode:port
root = /jobs/
```